# Jenkins - Maven(pom.xml) launch error: error in forked process

Tags: jenkins

When i tried launch pom.xml from jenkins(as maven project) on ubuntu linux (14.x),i am getting below error. Please help me on same.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test
>   (default-test) on project ui-test: Execution default-test of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed:
>   There was an error in the forked process [ERROR].

pom.xml:
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            4.0.0

```
        <groupId>com.siemens.fossology.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>ui-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>ui-test</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

            <main.class>com.siemens.fossology.test.ui.StartUp</main.class>

            <java.version>1.7</java.version>
            <config-builder.version>1.3.1</config-builder.version>
            <testng.version>6.9.8</testng.version>
            <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
            <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
            <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
            <mockito.version>1.10.8</mockito.version>
            <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
            <selenium-java.version>2.47.1</selenium-java.version>
            <xml-apis.version>1.4.01</xml-apis.version>

            <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
            <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.5</maven-jar-plugin.version>
            <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.4</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
            <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>

        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
                <artifactId>config-builder</artifactId>
                <version>${config-builder.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>${testng.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>${guava.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>${logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                <version>${logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>${selenium-java.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>${xml-apis.version}</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
             <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>report</id>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/xmlsoap/schemas/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>org/apache/ws/commons/schema/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement> 
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin> 



                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>

                </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.15</version>
                    </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer                                       implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                    </transformer>
                                    <transformer                                       implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                    </transformer>
                                    <transformer                                       implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                    </transformer>
                                    <transformer                                           implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                        <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                                <shadedClassifierName>with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Can anybody please guide me

Comment: i figured out the same, problem was with my TestNG xml , a class was misnamed here compare to the original project.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've seen this error is when I've upgraded the maven compiler plugin  (I happened to go from 3.5.1 to 3.6.0) and have been using the command line.  I just had to do a `mvn clean install` and it fixed the error.